# TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

how to solve this problem? I'm retrieving data from firestore database.

> TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Below is my code pushing the data to my events array but encountered this error:

```
 let events: any = [];

  const q = query(collection(DB, `events/${userType}/${uid}`));
  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      events.push({ ...doc.data() });
    });
  });
  return events;
```

Comment: Which line is this error from? I'm not positive you've got the right code here. And why not give events a type like `Array<any>` or `Array<SomeInterface>`

Comment: Probably `events.push` but my feeling is that `events` is different variable than you expect, shadowed by some other definition you didn't show between the `let` and the `push`.

Comment: Or - maybe this is an async issue, it seems you are returning `events` before the query even completed. Maybe the caller of your function calls `Object.freeze` on the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your events array and handle your return functionality within the onSnapshot method.

```
const q = query(collection(DB, `events/${userType}/${uid}`));
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
 let events: any = [];
 querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   events.push({ ...doc.data() });
 });
 setEventsState(events)
});
return;
```